# Multiple ROC curves in one plot ROCR

Tags: r, plot, roc

Is it possible to plot the roc curve for diffrent classifiers in the same plot using the ROCR package? I've tried:

```
>plot(perf.neuralNet, colorize=TRUE)
>lines(perf.randomForest)
```

But I get:

> Error en as.double(y) :
> cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'

Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem with your `lines`-approach is that there is no generic `S4` lines function for an object of class `performance` defined in the `ROCR` package. But you can use the generic plot function as you did with an additional `add = TRUE` argument. For example this is partly from the example page of `?plot.performance`:

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels )
pred2 <- prediction(abs(ROCR.simple$predictions + 
                        rnorm(length(ROCR.simple$predictions), 0, 0.1)), 
        ROCR.simple$labels)
perf <- performance( pred, "tpr", "fpr" )
perf2 <- performance(pred2, "tpr", "fpr")
plot( perf, colorize = TRUE)
plot(perf2, add = TRUE, colorize = TRUE)
```

OR, you can store all your predictions in a matrix and do all the subsequent steps in one:

```
preds <- cbind(p1 = ROCR.simple$predictions, 
                p2 = abs(ROCR.simple$predictions + 
                rnorm(length(ROCR.simple$predictions), 0, 0.1)))

pred.mat <- prediction(preds, labels = matrix(ROCR.simple$labels, 
                nrow = length(ROCR.simple$labels), ncol = 2) )

perf.mat <- performance(pred.mat, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf.mat, colorize = TRUE)
```

Btw, if you for some reason really wanted to use `lines` to plot consecutive ROC curves you would have to do sth. like this:

```
plot(perf) 
lines(perf2@x.values[[1]], perf2@y.values[[1]], col = 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Echoing @adibender, and adding a comment: the example doesn't cover how to set separate colors for each individual curve using the second (plot all at once) approach. In this case, pass col as a list:

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.hiv)
x   <- prediction(ROCR.hiv$hiv.nn$predictions, ROCR.hiv$hiv.nn$labels)
ROC <- performance(x, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(ROC, col = as.list(1:10))
```

Answer (score 1):

R has functions for draw several plots in one window. And if package doesn't support several plots in one window,you can solve problem with standard instruments of R. Other way: [Example of several ROCs](https://github.com/chupvl/R_scripts) 
Article with this script:[An example of ROC curves plotting with ROCR](http://www.r-bloggers.com/an-example-of-roc-curves-plotting-with-rocr/)

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that this solutions seems to be for cross-validation data, so it's not possible for example to add a legend to distinguish which curve belong to which classifier. And which are the instruments for drawing several plots in the same window?

Comment: You can use function subplot  or see this document:  [link] http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html