# Passing object to lines function ifor plot data

Tags: r, plot, graph, roc

My issue is the following. I use `ROCR` package to plot data.  `performance` function returns an object that I pass to plot the data like this:

```
example <- performance(prediction1,"tpr","fpr")
plot(example,col="red")
```

I want to add another `performance` object to this plot, but `lines` function accepts `x` and `y` coords and not an object. In fact if I do: `lines(example2, col="blue")` this error appears:

> Error in as.double(y) : 
>         cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'**

Comment: Maybe you want to `plot` the 2nd `performance` object by using `plot(example2, add = TRUE)`? Check here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085281/multiple-roc-curves-in-one-plot-rocr

Comment: Thank a lot, it work :); there is a way to giva a name to a line using plot with add=T ??

Comment: You mean to add a legend somewhere in the plot? You can check this: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/add-legends-to-plots-in-r-software-the-easiest-way

Comment: I pass an object to plot, in this case the object is "example". the plot is a list of 4 element then the plot has 4 lines. I want to use different line types for every line (1 -> point; 2->point and lines,....). How can i do this passing a list of 4 element????

Comment: I think you need to post that as a new question. Please, be specific with what data you have (i.e. post specific example) and show/describe your ideal output.

Comment: @Will Arrow, could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

You can add new line with `add = TRUE` as `plot` argument:

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)

prediction1 <- prediction( ROCR.simple$predictions, ROCR.simple$labels)
example1 <- performance(prediction1,"tpr","fpr")
plot(example1, col="red")
example2 <- performance(prediction1, "sens", "spec")
plot(example2, col="blue", add = TRUE)
```

[image: plots]